# load different activities in tabs

Tags: android, tabs

It took quite a while searching stackoverflow and google and can not find a guide to properly explain to me how to implement Tabs in my application.

I know it should not be used TabActivity, I also read about the recommendation not to use TabHost (at least that understanding). My interest is not just changing the content is run a full activity when changing tab.

#### Example

```
MainActivity:
   - Tab1Activity
   - Tab2Activity
   - Tab3Activity
```

My goal is to build an application that is supported by a wide range of devices from api 8 to the latest. I'm using `android-support-v4.jar`.

My second goal is to load in each tab an activity because at least two of them consume enough resources and speed should always prevail.

Can help me with a guide or explain a "correct" way to achieve this.

Comment: I would go for `Fragments` and implement a tab navigation in the action bar; check out http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/actionbar.html or http://www.java2s.com/Code/Android/UI/Usingactionbartabsandhowtheyinteractwithotheractionbarfeatures.htm

Comment: If you really want a "correct" way then listen to the advice to use `Fragments` instead of `Activities` as your tab content. You *can* use a `TabHost` if you want but using `Activities` for the tab content will cause you a lot of hassle. Trust me, I know what I'm talking about - I'm currently porting an Android app that used `TabActivity` with 7 tabs each with a separate `Activity` and it had got too complex. Using `Fragments` is way more flexible and allows me to reduce my code a great deal.

Comment: Activities in tabs has been a deprecated technique for over two years.

Comment: @Squonk Can you provide me an example of tabs without TabHost?

Comment: @rkmax : The documentation for `ActionBar.newTab(...)` has example code - see the link for ActionBar posted in the comment by Andre above. Note the v4 compatibility packages don't provide an `ActionBar` implementation but you can use `ActionBarSherlock` http://actionbarsherlock.com/

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should use Tabs with Fragments.

Look this : http://android.codeandmagic.org/2011/07/android-tabs-with-fragments/

Comment: I've read that tutorial. in fact I have the tab open but does not show how to create new Activities for each tab, so I made myself some of the examples of the SDK. thanks but that it's not the answwer i'm looking

Comment: Activities with tabs is deprecated. For future versions of Android You shouldn't use Activities

Comment: I'll try again, sure as I was exhausted but now I have new batteries

Answer (score 2):

As the other suggested, the best way to implement tabs in your application is to use fragments.

You should not use activities contained in a tabactivity, which is currently deprecated. Even the official documentation [suggests to use fragments](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/TabActivity.html), stating that

> New applications should use Fragments instead of this class

However, if you still feel *retro'* and you REALLY want to use tab contained activities, you need to use tabhost. A nice tutorial can be found [here](http://www.androidpeople.com/android-tabhost-tutorial-part-1), but again, I strongly recommend to go for the fragment way.