# Android tabhost with different activities

Tags: android, android-tabhost

I already wrote 2 activities and now I want them to be in a tabHost (2 tabs, each activity in a tab).

I saw some code but none of them was good for me.
The 2 activities are complicated so I can't marge them into one class.

What can I do ?

Thanks.

Comment: "2 tabs, each activity in a tab" -- putting activities in tabs was deprecated as a technique **over four years ago**. Please use a modern tab solution (`ViewPager` and a tabbed indicator, `FragmenTabHost`, etc.).

Comment: I agree with Mr. Murphy, see my answer, and here you can find another question about it http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15486686/load-different-activities-in-tabs

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you could do this, i mean load several Activities at the same time you will have memory issues, You should use Tabs with `Fragments`, so i suggest the use of `FragmentTabHost`, convert your activities into `Fragments` and load it in a `FragmentTabHost`, this is an example:

```
<android.support.v4.app.FragmentTabHost
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@android:id/tabhost"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

<LinearLayout
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <TabWidget
        android:id="@android:id/tabs"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="0"/>

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@android:id/tab_content1"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="0"/>
    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/tab_content2"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"/>

</LinearLayout>
</android.support.v4.app.FragmentTabHost>
```